# get key and value from comboBox where item bind from hashtable

Tags: c#, combobox

i have a combobox..

```
ComboBox searchKeyComboBox = new ComboBox() { Left = 100, Top = 22, Width = 230, DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList, DataSource = null };
```

where i fill it from hashtable like this..

```
Hashtable fieldTable = new Hashtable();
fieldTable.Add("kore", "Kode");
fieldTable.Add("keerere", "Keterangan");

 BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
 bs.DataSource = fieldTable;
 searchKeyComboBox.DataSource = bs;
 searchKeyComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
```

now that combobox "searchKeyComboBox" already filled with item's "Kode" and "Keterangan"...

how can i get that key and value from that combobox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the hashtable itself can be seen as a collection of `DictionaryEntry` elements, the `SelectedItem` of the combobox will be a DictionaryEntry and the key and values can be obtained from it:

```
var de  = (DictionaryEntry)searchKeyComboBox.SelectedItem;
var key = de.Key;
var value = de.Value;
```